# Cannot add data files to target table because that table is partitioned and contains non-identity partition transforms which will not be compatible

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I am integrating iceberg with spark , I tried to create the table test partitioned by hour(EndTime) ,

```
create table local.db.test (
MSISDN string,
START_TIME timestamp,
END_TIME timestamp
)
USING iceberg PARTITIONED BY (hours(END_TIME));
```

then I tried to call a procedure to insert data from parquet files ,

```
CALL local.system.add_files(
  table => 'local.db.test',
  source_table => '`parquet`.`path/to/parquet/files`'
);
```

I assume it should work , but got this exception ,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add data files to target
> table local.db.test because that table is partitioned and contains
> non-identitypartition transforms which will not be compatible. Found
> non-identity fields [1000: END_TIME_hour: hour(3)]